# Visual C++: генерация случайных чисел

Tags: c++, visual-studio, случайные-числа

Помогите пожалуйста написать генератор случайных чисел random (задали по учебе, а я не понимаю ничего) в промежутке от 1 до 15 по 3 числа (пример генерирования: 1)2-3-4, 2)5-6-7, 3)8-2-15 и т.д.).

Comment: Если не знаете как делать, то найдите как. RU SO не сервис по написанию лабораторных работ.

Comment: попробуйте написать хоть что-то иначе зачем оно вам?

Comment: В С++ есть стандартная библиотека для работы со случайными числами. Копайте в ее сторону. Для примера можете ознакомиться со следующими ссылками: [раз](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) и [два](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). Там же есть и примеры. Попробуйте, возможно, все у Вас получится. А если не получится, то уже с конкретными вопросами, что именно не получается и фрагментами кода, обращайтесь за помощью.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, пожалуйста:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(1, 15);
    std::cout << distr(rd) << ' ' << distr(rd) << ' ' << distr(rd) << '\n';
}
```

Всегда рады помочь простым и качественным кодом.