# задать диапазон случайных чисел [-5;5]

Tags: c++

как задать диапазон случайных чисел [-5;5]

Comment: А для какого распределения?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Visual C++: генерация случайных чисел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498795/visual-c-%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два решения.

Хорошее:

```
random_device rd;
default_random_engine u(rd());
uniform_int_distribution<> distr(-5, 5);
```

Случайные значения получаются как

```
distr(u);
```

И простое:

```
rand()%11-5;
```

Выбирайте сами.